# How to handle NavigationView PaneFooter Settings item click

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

When adding a `NavigationView` a 'Settings' item is automatically added at the bottom of the `NavigationView`. How can a click event be added to this item since it doesn't appear to be accessible from XAML?

```
<Page
    x:Class="My_Project.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <NavigationView>
            <NavigationView.PaneFooter>
            </NavigationView.PaneFooter>
        </NavigationView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can a click event be added to this item since it doesn't appear to be accessible from XAML?

The Settings button click event is already handled by the [NavigationView.ItemInvoked Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.ItemInvoked?view=winrt-19041). This is mentioned in the document [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview#navigation) as "When the user taps on a navigation item, the navigation view shows that item as selected and raises an **ItemInvoked event**. "

So you just need to handle the NavigationView.ItemInvoked Event and check the [NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs.IsSettingsInvoked Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewiteminvokedeventargs.issettingsinvoked?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs.IsSettingsInvoked);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=winrt-19041).

Here is the code that you could refer to:

```
 <Grid>
    <NavigationView ItemInvoked="NavigationView_ItemInvoked">
        <NavigationView.PaneFooter>
        </NavigationView.PaneFooter>
    </NavigationView>
</Grid>
```

In code behind:

```
 private void NavigationView_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsSettingsInvoked == true) 
        {
           //do something

        }
    }
```

**Update**

If you want to check if the item is a specific one, you could set a tag property in the Xaml for the navigationview item and then check this property in the  **ItemInvoked event**.

In xaml:

```
 <NavigationViewItem Tag="home" Icon="Home" Content="Home"/>
```

In code behind:

```
  private void NavigationView_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        var navItemTag = args.InvokedItemContainer.Tag.ToString();
        if (navItemTag.Equals("home")) 
        {
            // do something
            Debug.WriteLine("test");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about an `if` statement to check which specific item was clicked? e.g. If the clicked item contains the string resource "Item A", do something.

Comment: @MacaronLover, of course, you can, I've updated my answer and you could check it.

Comment: @MacaronLover Do you have any other questions?

Comment: Have you people ever heard of MVVM? How are we supposed to access this property from a View Model???